# jQuery increment of the number in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get number in the div to be  increment +1 with the jQuery

The original code looks like this:

```
<div class="timeline">
<div class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__item__icon-wrap">
         <div class="timeline__item__icon">
             1
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__item__content padding-left">
         <div class="timeline__item__description">
              <h3>Day 1</h3>
             <p>t   t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="timeline__item">
     <div class="timeline__item__icon-wrap">
         <div class="timeline__item__icon">
             1
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="timeline__item__content padding-left">
         <div class="timeline__item__description">
             <h3>Day 2</h3>
             <p>t   t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t</p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline__item">
     <div class="timeline__item__icon-wrap">
         <div class="timeline__item__icon">
              1
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="timeline__item__content padding-left">
         <div class="timeline__item__description">
             <h3>Day 3</h3>
             <p>t   t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t  t</p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Those 1 in .timeline__item__icon should return 1 , 2, 3...

I have tried with

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var number = 1;
 jQuery( ".timeline__item__icon-wrap > div > div" ).replaceWith( number );
return ++number;
});
```

Comment: Where is you attempt to solve this. Also, why don't you just put the correct numbers in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.timeline__item__icon').each((i, e) => $(e).text(i+1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline__item__icon">
  1
</div>
<div class="timeline__item__icon">
  1
</div>
<div class="timeline__item__icon">
  1
</div>
```